# Download zip files using axios

Tags: reactjs, download, axios

I am working on a react project where I'm getting a zip file as a response to REST API, I've to download the same and save it in client's machine. The size of the zip file can vary from 100mb to 800mb.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: when I'm trying to unzip its giving me error. when I'm using the same request in postman its working fine.

Comment: Can you add some code, like what the request looks like?

Comment: sorry, can't share the code. the api works fine because i have tested the generated request over postman and it downloads the zip file and i'm able to see the content.